# Session cache in Objectify is not updated for update of the entity. It returns only the stale data

Tags: objectify

I am working on a we Maven Multimodule project in google appengine. There are 3 modules. default, backend and api. backend and api are the modules that uses objectify to store data and default contains the front end code. All the web related requests from default module are handled by backend module and works perfectly. But the api module is where I am facing the issue. Some data is pushed from external apps through the api and is being saved or updated in this app using Objectify. When I try to fetch the same to show it on the page details section after, the stale data (un updated data) is being returned. I don't face this issue, when the request is through UI.

Note : 1. I configured ObjectifyFilter in web.xml for both backend and api modules. I believe, this does the cleanup work upon updates/ save. It is configured for all endpoints in the app. (/*)

2. This occurs only after the update for this Entity. All the Entities are Registered.
3. Using ofy.clear() before load() works well. I believe this clears the session cache.
4. No Problem with the Filter orders (there is one extra Auth filter in addition to Objectify Filter.) . ObjectifyFilter takes priority as I configured above the AuthFilter.
5. I was using basic-scaling, but later on removed it by seeing a github thread on the Objectifyfilter topic, but no luck in solving this.
6. Similar issue popped up in one more place, But I handled it as separate task queue as it is a dependent task (triggered when another entity is saved / updated). But this is a unitary operation.

The fetch code that i use right now is

```
log.info("DAO :: fetch()");
        if(ofy.isLoaded(Key.create(Class.forName(className),key))) {
            log.info("session cache is loaded and key is present in it.");
            ofy.clear();
        }else {
            log.info("session cache is not loaded and key is not present in it. ==========> ofy.clear()");
        }
        entity = (DAO) ofy.load().type(Class.forName(className)).id(key).now();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session cache *always* returns the present content of the session. You need to be aware of the scope of the session while working - if you're using the `ObjectifyFilter`, by default you have a session cache for one single request. You can create new session scopes by running `ObjectifyService.run()` or starting transactions. Sessions are single-threaded, only relevant to a single thread of execution, and should be short-lived.

If you're trying to get multiple processes or threads of execution to interact with common data in a meaningful way, you probably want transactions. Transactions are the only way to guarantee a consistent view of data in the datastore - even without a session cache, data is stale the moment you read it (someone else could have changed it one nanosecond later). Transactions solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to help on this. I am not handling this in transaction as it deals with only one entity (Unitary operation). Same code works well, when the request was from UI. But , when the request was through the API, from another app, I am facing this issue. I believe, in my case scope of the request stays same in both cases. But in one case it works, and in another case it fails...Can you help me figure out or any suggestions for debugging this issue?

Comment: I can't really figure out what you're trying to do from the question, I'm afraid. If you're using sessions properly (ie, not holding open a session forever), you won't see excessively stale data. You could also be seeing eventual consistency? Hard to tell. Maybe try to rephrase the question with more detail about what you are doing and what you expect to see.

Comment: Hello. sorry for the delay in reply. I agree with your answer. Thank you for reaching out quickly. The problem with my case is I trigger a appengine task queue in the same request that comes in through ObjectifyFilter. Only Issue, I fail to understand is why at times the updates through task queue is not cascaded to session cache.

Comment: The session cache is a thread-local in your instance. It's tied to a single thread of execution. Once an entity is loaded into the session, that's the entity you get when you load it from that thread. An update to the database (through the task queue, say) will not be visible to a session - that's the nature of a session. If you need a consistent view of the database across multiple threads of execution, you need transactions.

Comment: I understood now. Thank you very much for the assistance and explanation.